# Зонт или зонтик?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Насколько я знаю, изначально было "зонтик". Потом сократилось до "зонт". Но как все-таки правильнее говорить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На русском, естественно, зонт. Зонтик - уменьшительное. Обе формы широко употребительны.
Касательно этимологии. Ходит байка, что исходным заимствованием было голландское zondek, означающее якобы "защита от солнца". От него произошёл зонтик, и только потом зонт.
В этой истории несомненно то, что первые зонты действительно защищали не от дождя, а от солнца, но голландское слово zondek вряд ли могло быть названием такого устройства, поскольку означает не защиту, а нечто прямо противоположное - пляж, солярий.
По более "продвинутой" версии zondek позаимствовано не из голландского как такового, а из его морского "диалекта", где якобы означало "навес над палубой". Но если исходить из "калечного" перевода, то получится максимум "солнечная палуба", ключевого-то слова "навес" там как раз и нет.

Comment: Вот интересно, кто "запускает" такие этимологические версии "в народ"? Про "кенгуру" еще...  

Кстати, независимо от голландского языка, что же все-таки было исходным: зонт или зонтик? И откуда это слово?  
Фасмер:  
> род. п. зонта́, зо́нтик; стар. зондек "тент, полотно или парусина, растягиваемые над палубой (для защиты от солнца и дождя)", Уст. морск. 1720 г.; см. Смирнов 117. Первонач. слово морск. языка, заимств. из голл. zondek "защита от солнца". Зонт – новообразование от зо́нтик; см. Мёлен 244; Преобр. I, 256.

Comment: Эта версия как раз не "народная" - и заслуживает пристального рассмотрения. Просто объяснение неполное или неточное. Фасмер, будучи немцем, не мог не чувствовать близгородственного голландского. Но вот с навесом десйствительно проблема.    
Других версий я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос как правильно произносить иностранное слово по-русски не имеет смысла. Выбирайте любой вариант. А этимологически да, зонтик - начальный вариант, по крайней мере других версий происхождения нет.

Answer (score 0):

До 19 века был зонтик и сейчас большинство называют зонтиком, но есть те немногие, кот сократили как зонт.